# Control padding in SwiftUI Table cells

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app (macOS only) that uses a Table to show contents of a directory. Each Table Cell seems to have a padding / gap which I would like to remove. If you look at the picture, I want the red rectangle to fill the whole cell. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

[image]

Here's my current code for that column:

```swift
TableColumn("name", value: \.name) { item in
    HStack {
        if item.type == .directory {
            Image(systemName: "folder")
                .frame(width: 14)
        } else {
            Text("")
                .frame(width: 14)
        }
        Text(item.name)
        Spacer()
    }
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .gesture(TapGesture(count: 2).onEnded {
        print(item)
        doubleClick(path: item.path)
    }).simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
        self.selectedFileItem = item.id
    })
    .background(.red)
    .padding(.all, 0)
}
```

I want this to be applied to all columns in the table. I only showed one column as a reference. The table style is

```
.tableStyle(.bordered(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))
```

I couldn't really find any way to solve this. I tried setting the padding to 0 everywhere as well. But I get the feeling that this is a limitation for SwiftUI tables. I don't want to switch to AppKit right now.

Is there anything I am missing?